# Signing Identity dropdown list is empty after upgrading Visual Studio 2019 on Windows platform

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

Building iOS apps with Xamarin.Forms on Windows using Visual Studio is real struggle. Every single day I have endless weird problems...

I've successfully distributed an app yesterday. Today I cannot sign the archive anymore because the Signing Identity dropdown list is empty:

[image]

I download all the profiles at Project Properties page:

[image]

My older archives are lost either. I hate those minor VS updates; many of them larger than GBs and cause conflicts when you develop at more than one machine plus Mac device.

How can get the identity back that I've downloaded?

P.S: Removing & re-adding the Apple account didn't work. I could rebuilt,re-archived and then distributed using other pc. Notice the Signing Identity, it's not automatic this time.

[image]

Comment: You can report a problem inside visual-stuido. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release) about Installing an earlier release.

Comment: If he installs a downgrade, the Visual Studio version is not compatible with the current XCode version. Correct? Then you could sign but not build.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Tools > Options > Apple Accounts
   [image]
2. Add your Apple ID and validate.
3. Scroll Down there is a list of your teams
   [image]
4. Select one and go to "View Details"
5. Here you can add certificates and download profiles, or import them from your Mac key chain.
   [image]
6. Go to the bundle signing section and select the correct profile.